# Browser doesn't store cookies

Tags: cookies, vuejs2, laravel-5.6

I'm sending Cookie from Laravel application (`http://backend.local`) to Vue SPA (`http://frontend.local:8080`):

#### Laravel side (dummy route)

```
//api routes
Route::post('login', function () {
    setcookie("name", 'value', time()+3600, "/", ".local");
    return response('ok');
});
```

#### Vue side

```
axios.post('//backend.local/api/login')
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
    }).catch(error => {
})
```

Response Headers:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Date: Mon, 21 May 2018 09:42:35 GMT
>   Server: Apache
>   Set-Cookie: name=value; expires=Mon, 21-May-2018 10:42:36 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=.local
>   Cache-Control: no-cache, private
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://frontend.local:8080
>   Vary: Origin
>   X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
>   X-RateLimit-Remaining: 59
>   Content-Length: 2
>   Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=100
>   Connection: Keep-Alive
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

But there is no Cookies in broswer storage (Application tab in Developers Console).
What's wrong?

---

UPDATE: I think the problem is that there is port number in `http://frontend.local:8080`. Can I remove port number from url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Original Answer**

The browser will automatically reject any domain which doesn't have two parts to it. So using `.local` is not considered a domain at all. You need to two levels at least. Consider the below flask app I created for demoing the same

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    resp = make_response()

    resp.set_cookie('value1', ".frontend.local", domain=".frontend.local")
    resp.set_cookie('value2', "frontend.local", domain="frontend.local")
    resp.set_cookie('value3', ".local", domain=".local")
    return resp

app.run(debug=True)
```

Now testing this through curl

```
$ curl -v frontend.local:5000
* Rebuilt URL to: frontend.local:5000/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to frontend.local (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: frontend.local:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Set-Cookie: value1=.frontend.local; Domain=.frontend.local; Path=/
< Set-Cookie: value2=frontend.local; Domain=frontend.local; Path=/
< Set-Cookie: value3=.local; Domain=.local; Path=/
< Content-Length: 0
< Server: Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.6.5
< Date: Tue, 29 May 2018 12:58:20 GMT
<
* Closing connection 0
```

When you navigate this in browser, you can see that the cookie with `Domain=.local` gets discarded but rest 2 remains

[image: Cookies saved]

And later you can see that both the cookies have been sent to the reload of the same page

[image: Page reload cookies]

**Update 1: 30th May 2018**

Since you are using 2 different domains, you should use `frontend.local.com` and `backend.local.com` and the cookies should be returned with domain as `.local.com`, so that `backend` and `frontend` works as a subdomain of `local.com`. Then `frontend.local.com` gets the cookies set by `backend.local.com` through domain sharing as the cookie domain is set to `.local.com`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've just tried to send a Cookie with `frontend.local` and `.frontend.local` - there were no Cookies in browser...

Comment: @Tarasovych, since you are using 2 different domains. you should use `frontend.local.com` and `backend.local.com` and the cookies should be returned with domain as `.local.com`, so that `backend` works as a subdomain and `frontend` gets those cookies through domain sharing

Comment: Your comment is helpful! Please, add it to your answer! I may give +50 award in 17 hours.

Comment: @Tarasovych, I have updated the answer. Please just accept the answer and the bounty will be awarded automatically at the end. This gives more visibility to both the question and answer

Comment: I'm not the creator of the question, so let's wait if origin creator accept your answer.

Comment: @h1784487, let us know your feedback

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thank you! Your answer was helpful! I've just created two fresh projects - `frontend.local.xyz` and `backend.local.xyz`. And I got the same problem (Cookie Headers exists but no Cookie in Application tab).
Yesterday I had also created two fresh projects `frontend.local.com` and `backend.local.com` and everything was ok. Maybe there are some other issues which affect setting Cookies in browser?

Comment: Show a screenshot of returned cookies from network tab?

Comment: This looks good as such. Can you create a minimal repo for me to check?

Comment: @TarunLalwani so I've created two clean projects: [frontend](https://github.com/Tarasovych/admin.domain.com) and [backend](https://github.com/Tarasovych/api.domain.com). I've tested my own routes. I got Cookies in browser and Cross-Domain Request Error at the same time. Than I've installed some package which handle Cross-Domain Requests on backend. I've tested one more - no Cookies. I've removed that package and tested one more - no Cookies. Magic. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a CORS call, you will need to set `setCredentials` to `true`. This is a standard behavior: **Standard CORS requests do not send or set any cookies by default.**

The `withCredentials` property will include any cookies from the other domain in the request and also set any cookies from other domain.

So your `Vue.js` code will be:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '//backend.local/api/login',

    // THIS IS IMPORTANT
    withCredentials: true
})
.then(response => {
    console.log(response)
}).catch(error => {})
```

*[Edit]: Read more about CORS at [HTML Rocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/).*

Please let me know if it doesn't help.

Comment: It didn't help(

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the only thing required to make CORS cookies work. You can do two things. First, try setting the default value of withCredentials to true: axios.defaults.withCredentials = true; before you make a request. See if it works. I heard weird things with axios about CORS POSTS. Second, manually set a cookie from dev tools in your chrome/firefox browser and then make the Ajax call. Check if your cookie is being sent in the request header. If yes, then it is some other problem. Otherwise problem with axios.

Comment: I've tried to set cookie manually and send a request. Cookie didn't reached server. Seems like problem with axios. I'll try other ways to send request from Vue to server than.